# Show custom UI for VoIP incoming and outgoing call and insert call details inside recents in phone app

Tags: ios, voip, callkit

All code present on StackOverFlow shows me how to show native phone call UI for outgoing and incoming calls. But I want this:

1. Show custom UI for Incoming call if app is in active state.

I will show my own UI, but want to report the system that a call has been received. But when I call `reportNewIncomingCall` method of CXProvider class it will automatically show native phone call UI even when the app is in `UIApplicationStateActive` state.

How to make an entry for receiving/answering calls showing custom UI instead of native call UI?

Comment: Consider removing the second part of the title. The question is only about one of the two arguments cited in the title.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to show a custom UI while the reported incoming call is ringing. One of the reasons could be that they wanted the UI to be consistent regardless of the phone state. Moreover, in this way they could probably achieve better integration with the native calls.